# Relay optional query with usePreloadedQuery

Tags: reactjs, relay, relaymodern, react-relay

Let's say you have this use case:

A simple form with one input and a submit button.

When the input value is valid (>3 chars) you want to query the server to see if the value is already in use.

The button should be disabled when
A. input value is <4 chars
B. input value is already in use (response from server)

**I tried to do it with usePreloadedQuery**

The probleme is that the button that should always be visible will call usePreloadedQuery before a query is ever fired and therefore will throw because the queryRef is null.

**I tried to do it with useLazyLoadQuery**

I tried to use useLazyLoadQuery and set `{ fetchPolicy: value.length < 4 ? "store-only" : "network-or-store" }` but then it forces me to have a Suspense fallback higher which will make my component disappear on every key push over 3 chars.

What would be the best way to achieve this with Relay?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Really interested if you came up with something.